# Do we have anyway of knowing if avoiding self-permutation in RC4 makes it any stronger?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, attack, rc4

OK, so lots of questions get asked about RC4 but I want to make mine specific and hopefully answerable.

RC4 Design as I'm sure anyone reading this knows, uses self permutation in stage 1 of the KSA.

Is this KSA any better? Can we know easily? Is there proof from a security point of view, this is actually worse, can we safely assume it suffers most the flaws RC4 KSA suffers anyway and if we don't use this code:

```
for i from 0 to 255
    S[i] := i
endfor
j := 0
for i from 0 to 255
    j := (j + S[i] + key[i mod keylength]) mod 256
    swap values of S[i] and S[j]
endfor
```

****but instead use:****

```
    s[0] = 181: s[1] = 172: s[2] = 179: s[3] = 178: s[4] = 177: s[5] = 168: s[6] = 175: s[7] = 174: s[8] = 173: s[9] = 164: s[10] = 171: s[11] = 170: s[12] = 169: s[13] = 160: s[14] = 167: s[15] = 166: s[16] = 197: s[17] = 188: s[18] = 195: s[19] = 194: s[20] = 193: s[21] = 184: s[22] = 191: s[23] = 190: s[24] = 189: s[25] = 180: s[26] = 187: s[27] = 186: s[28] = 185: s[29] = 176: s[30] = 183
    s[31] = 182: s[32] = 213: s[33] = 204: s[34] = 211: s[35] = 210: s[36] = 209: s[37] = 200: s[38] = 207: s[39] = 206: s[40] = 205: s[41] = 196: s[42] = 203: s[43] = 202: s[44] = 201: s[45] = 192: s[46] = 199: s[47] = 198: s[48] = 101: s[49] = 92: s[50] = 99: s[51] = 98: s[52] = 97: s[53] = 216: s[54] = 223: s[55] = 222: s[56] = 221: s[57] = 212: s[58] = 219: s[59] = 218: s[60] = 217
    s[61] = 208: s[62] = 215: s[63] = 214: s[64] = 117: s[65] = 108: s[66] = 115: s[67] = 114: s[68] = 113: s[69] = 104: s[70] = 111: s[71] = 110: s[72] = 109: s[73] = 100: s[74] = 107: s[75] = 106: s[76] = 105: s[77] = 96: s[78] = 103: s[79] = 102: s[80] = 133: s[81] = 124: s[82] = 131: s[83] = 130: s[84] = 129: s[85] = 120: s[86] = 127: s[87] = 126: s[88] = 125: s[89] = 116: s[90] = 123
    s[91] = 122: s[92] = 121: s[93] = 112: s[94] = 119: s[95] = 118: s[96] = 149: s[97] = 140: s[98] = 147: s[99] = 146: s[100] = 145: s[101] = 136: s[102] = 143: s[103] = 142: s[104] = 141: s[105] = 132: s[106] = 139: s[107] = 138: s[108] = 137: s[109] = 128: s[110] = 135: s[111] = 134: s[112] = 37: s[113] = 28: s[114] = 35: s[115] = 34: s[116] = 33: s[117] = 152: s[118] = 159: s[119] = 158: s[120] = 157
    s[121] = 148: s[122] = 155: s[123] = 154: s[124] = 153: s[125] = 144: s[126] = 151: s[127] = 150: s[128] = 53: s[129] = 44: s[130] = 51: s[131] = 50: s[132] = 49: s[133] = 40: s[134] = 47: s[135] = 46: s[136] = 45: s[137] = 36: s[138] = 43: s[139] = 42: s[140] = 41: s[141] = 32: s[142] = 39: s[143] = 38: s[144] = 69: s[145] = 60: s[146] = 67: s[147] = 66: s[148] = 65: s[149] = 56: s[150] = 63
    s[151] = 62: s[152] = 61: s[153] = 52: s[154] = 59: s[155] = 58: s[156] = 57: s[157] = 48: s[158] = 55: s[159] = 54: s[160] = 85: s[161] = 76: s[162] = 83: s[163] = 82: s[164] = 81: s[165] = 72: s[166] = 79: s[167] = 78: s[168] = 77: s[169] = 68: s[170] = 75: s[171] = 74: s[172] = 73: s[173] = 64: s[174] = 71: s[175] = 70: s[176] = 229: s[177] = 220: s[178] = 227: s[179] = 226: s[180] = 225
    s[181] = 88: s[182] = 95: s[183] = 94: s[184] = 93: s[185] = 84: s[186] = 91: s[187] = 90: s[188] = 89: s[189] = 80: s[190] = 87: s[191] = 86: s[192] = 245: s[193] = 236: s[194] = 243: s[195] = 242: s[196] = 241: s[197] = 232: s[198] = 239: s[199] = 238: s[200] = 237: s[201] = 228: s[202] = 235: s[203] = 234: s[204] = 233: s[205] = 224: s[206] = 231: s[207] = 230: s[208] = 5: s[209] = 252: s[210] = 3
    s[211] = 2: s[212] = 1: s[213] = 248: s[214] = 255: s[215] = 254: s[216] = 253: s[217] = 244: s[218] = 251: s[219] = 250: s[220] = 249: s[221] = 240: s[222] = 247: s[223] = 246: s[224] = 21: s[225] = 12: s[226] = 19: s[227] = 18: s[228] = 17: s[229] = 8: s[230] = 15: s[231] = 14: s[232] = 13: s[233] = 4: s[234] = 11: s[235] = 10: s[236] = 9: s[237] = 0: s[238] = 7: s[239] = 6: s[240] = 165
    s[241] = 156: s[242] = 163: s[243] = 162: s[244] = 161: s[245] = 24: s[246] = 31: s[247] = 30: s[248] = 29: s[249] = 20: s[250] = 27: s[251] = 26: s[252] = 25: s[253] = 16: s[254] = 23: s[255] = 22

j := 0
       for i from 0 to 255
        j := (j + S[i] + key[i mod keylength]) mod 256
        swap values of S[i] and S[j]
    endfor
```

I can see we probably have probably created new problems and probably fixed some old ones. **Does anyone know how effective if at all, this less elegant KSA is?** (it's just as fast, in software at least but it loses all it's elegance. Is this AT BEST, "security through confusion" or does it have real advantages?

Comment: Likely, there exists some key that would result in the same initial setup of the $s$ array using regular RC4 that you are getting by using your initial setup of the $s$ array. So really, it would seem that given that key, your setup is equivalent to regular RC4 using a concatenated key (the special key I just mentioned and the actual key). So I doubt that your setup helps any.

Comment: @mikeazo Cheers for the response, like that's exactly what I suspect, I just wondered if anyone could elaborate on proof. I have actually used this permuation (that wasn't reached using the KSA but if I understand you right, you're saying it could be with some obscure multiple of bytes as a key. I guess my sub-question was does anyone know if this set-up makes RC4 any WORSE? (As I say, it's very fast to implement in software some set of numbers like this and the RC4 KSA is something I'm using inside another wider function, it's not being used as a stream cipher)

Comment: @mikeazo I just want to add, your answer is actually fantastic: you made what I thought was a semi-difficult problem, trivial as anything. The "...using a concatenated key", bit answers my entire question, when I think about it. Kudos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wanted to expand on my [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31770/do-we-have-anyway-of-knowing-if-avoiding-self-permutation-in-rc4-makes-it-any-st?noredirect=1#comment73835_31770) as an answer.

The KSA in RC4 permutes the bytes [0,1,...,255] using a key, say $k_u$. For any permutation of these bytes, there exists a key that will get you that permutation.

The idea you outline is basically to start by permuting the bytes [0,1,...,255] according to some fixed initial permutation, then permuting the bytes according to the key. Since that initial permutation could be described by some key, call it $k_{ip}$, what you in effect have is the bytes [0,1,...,255] permuted by $k_{ip}\;|\;k_u$ (where $|$ is concatenation).

So what you are really asking is, does prepending some key to the user passed in key make RC4 weaker, stronger, or have no effect. I am not super familiar with the attacks on RC4. It would seem that this initial permutation does not make RC4 any weaker. I doubt it makes it much stronger, if at all.

Comment: Technically, since RC4 key length is capped at 256 bytes (and the key is repeated if it's shorter than that), just concatenating $k_{ip}$ and $k_u$ won't work; you'd have to actually run the key setup twice, first with $k_{ip}$ and then with $k_u$. Still, for any initial permutation $p_1$ and any target permutation $p_2$, there is an RC4 key (possibly several, in fact, but at least one is easy to find) that transforms $p_1$ into $p_2$. In that sense, every key in the OP's modified RC4 is provably equivalent to some key in normal RC4.

Answer (score 4):

To build on [mikeazo's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31799) (since it's not really practical to post code in comments), here's a quick Python program that takes any two permutations of $\{0, \dots, 255\}$ and generates a key that transforms one into the other when run through the RC4 key setup:

```
# source and target permutations
s = range(256)
t = [181, 172, 179, 178, 177, 168, 175, 174, 173, 164, 171, 170, 169,
     160, 167, 166, 197, 188, 195, 194, 193, 184, 191, 190, 189, 180, 187,
     186, 185, 176, 183, 182, 213, 204, 211, 210, 209, 200, 207, 206, 205,
     196, 203, 202, 201, 192, 199, 198, 101, 92, 99, 98, 97, 216, 223, 222,
     221, 212, 219, 218, 217, 208, 215, 214, 117, 108, 115, 114, 113, 104,
     111, 110, 109, 100, 107, 106, 105, 96, 103, 102, 133, 124, 131, 130,
     129, 120, 127, 126, 125, 116, 123, 122, 121, 112, 119, 118, 149, 140,
     147, 146, 145, 136, 143, 142, 141, 132, 139, 138, 137, 128, 135, 134,
     37, 28, 35, 34, 33, 152, 159, 158, 157, 148, 155, 154, 153, 144, 151,
     150, 53, 44, 51, 50, 49, 40, 47, 46, 45, 36, 43, 42, 41, 32, 39, 38,
     69, 60, 67, 66, 65, 56, 63, 62, 61, 52, 59, 58, 57, 48, 55, 54, 85,
     76, 83, 82, 81, 72, 79, 78, 77, 68, 75, 74, 73, 64, 71, 70, 229, 220,
     227, 226, 225, 88, 95, 94, 93, 84, 91, 90, 89, 80, 87, 86, 245, 236,
     243, 242, 241, 232, 239, 238, 237, 228, 235, 234, 233, 224, 231, 230,
     5, 252, 3, 2, 1, 248, 255, 254, 253, 244, 251, 250, 249, 240, 247,
     246, 21, 12, 19, 18, 17, 8, 15, 14, 13, 4, 11, 10, 9, 0, 7, 6, 165,
     156, 163, 162, 161, 24, 31, 30, 29, 20, 27, 26, 25, 16, 23, 22]

# build RC4 key that transforms s into t
k = []
j = 0
for i in range(256):
    k.append( (s.index(t[i]) - j - s[i]) & 255 )
    j = (j + s[i] + k[i]) & 255
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]

print k
```

For your specific permutation, shown as `t` above, this program generates the following key bytes:

```
k = [181, 246, 5, 252, 251, 242, 1, 248, 247, 238, 253, 244, 243, 234,
     249, 240, 15, 230, 245, 236, 235, 226, 241, 232, 231, 222, 237, 228,
     227, 218, 233, 224, 255, 214, 229, 220, 219, 210, 225, 216, 215, 206,
     221, 212, 211, 202, 217, 208, 111, 198, 213, 204, 203, 66, 209, 200,
     199, 190, 205, 196, 195, 186, 201, 192, 95, 182, 197, 188, 187, 178,
     193, 184, 183, 174, 189, 180, 179, 170, 185, 176, 207, 166, 181, 172,
     171, 162, 177, 168, 167, 158, 173, 164, 206, 154, 169, 160, 210, 195,
     212, 205, 182, 199, 184, 177, 186, 171, 188, 181, 190, 175, 192, 185,
     229, 173, 214, 191, 160, 140, 168, 161, 170, 198, 172, 165, 174, 159,
     176, 169, 250, 157, 119, 173, 182, 233, 179, 186, 201, 208, 175, 182,
     197, 204, 171, 178, 174, 187, 167, 174, 178, 191, 163, 170, 185, 163,
     188, 166, 93, 151, 192, 162, 212, 112, 96, 92, 233, 111, 232, 241, 10,
     208, 7, 245, 14, 239, 240, 249, 2, 243, 4, 253, 230, 244, 235, 225,
     213, 245, 247, 229, 225, 233, 243, 233, 18, 227, 244, 237, 246, 231,
     1, 248, 234, 235, 253, 244, 238, 223, 249, 240, 239, 126, 68, 93, 91,
     31, 241, 232, 90, 91, 237, 228, 251, 239, 233, 224, 223, 222, 109, 92,
     222, 234, 231, 243, 254, 235, 230, 247, 242, 239, 239, 251, 241, 227,
     91, 95, 245, 236, 223, 227, 246, 230, 227, 231, 232, 241, 234, 235]
```

Note that RC4 has equivalent keys, as easily shown by a pigeonhole argument: the key space, even after unrolling keys to the full length, has $256^{256}$ elements, while the internal state space (ignoring $i$ and $j$, which are always initialized to $0$) has only $256! \approx 256^{210.5}$ possible initial states.

Thus, the key returned by the code above is typically not the only solution.  It is, however, the unique full-length RC4 key mapping $s$ to $t$ while also satisfying the additional constraint that $j \ge i$ after every iteration of the key setup loop.

In particular, this program demonstrates that:

- every possible permutation of the RC4 internal state array is obtainable using the standard RC4 key setup algorithm, and
- this holds regardless of the initial permutation; changing this permutation thus effectively only amounts to a remapping of the key space.

(Note that this does not contradict the well known existence of unreachable [Finney states](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.crypt/JsO3xEATGFA/nelEG6RoUxcJ) in RC4; the reason those states are unreachable is because the $i$ and $j$ indices are both reset to zero after the key setup, and thus the initial state can never satisfy the Finney invariant $j = i+1 \bmod 256, S[j] = 1$.)

Comment: @IamNick: All the 256! permutations can, indeed, be reached; to show this, first note that a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) can produce any permutation, and then that any execution of the Fisher-Yates shuffle on {0, ..., 255} can be simulated by RC4 key setup with a suitably chosen key. In fact, this directly yields an algorithm for reconstructing the key based on the final permutation, which is exactly what I've presented above. [...]

Comment: ... However, the RC4 internal state also includes the $i$ and $j$ indices, which are initialized to fixed values; thus, the full RC4 state space has $256^2 \cdot 256!$ states, of which only $256!$ (those with $i=j=0$) are possible on the first round (and some, like the Finney states, are provably unreachable on any round).

Comment: That's some very informative extra info, thank you. 

I had always realised the initial possible states should be 256! (or 8.5781777510 e+507) at most.

My problem was, I thought, I read somewhere that, not all 256! permutations could exist, not even from a 2048 bit key. That said since I'm here to ask and learn or I wouldn't have asked, I'll happily take the collective wisdom of both of you. The question was always specifically about the KSA, so I consider it well and truly answered. Many Thanks.